# Why this Python boolean 'if' statement doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

```
roll_number = [47, 64, 69, 37, 76, 83, 95, 97]
sample_dict = {'John': 47, 'Emma': 69, 'Kelly': 76, 'Jason': 97}

for i in list(roll_number):
    if i in sample_dict.values() is False: 
        roll_number.remove(i) #it doesnt come down here, even though it gets 'False' before

print(roll_number)
```

`i in sample_dict.values()` returns `False`, I checked it by printing result of this condition by itself, outside of `if` statement, but my programm doesn't go to `roll_number.remove(i)` like it doesn't get `False`, but it does, so I don't understand what's wrong.

Comment: Do you want to remove i when i is in sample_dict values?

Comment: `if i not in sample_dict.values(): `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have already showed you how to fix this. The problem was this condition:

```py
if i in sample_dict.values() is False
```

is gonna be interpreted like below(except that `sample_dict.values()` only gets evaluated once):

```py
if (i in sample_dict.values()) and (sample_dict.values() is False):
```

They are called chained comparison operators. [Read more here](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons).

Answer (score 0):

The syntax you're looking for is

```
if i not in sample_dict.values():
```

Your syntax works as well if we add another pair of parentheses

```
# Don't do this though
if (i in sample_dict.values()) is False:
```

This defines the order of the operations to match what you're trying to do `-> if True is False:`. Otherwise it's two comparisons in a row, which results in unwanted results as stated by @S.B in another answer `-> if True and False:`.

Also, the cast of `roll_numbers` to a list in the for loop is redundant - the variable is already a list.

Comment: You **must not** use `is False` (or `is True`). It's logically incorrect and can also fail *in practice*. For example, numpy uses some logical operations that return a proxy class for boolean values test equal to `True` and `False` but which are not object-identical to `True` and `False` (so testing them with `is` *will fail!*).

Comment: Interesting, I remember learning that `is` should be used with `False`, `True` and `None`. I do get what you're saying but I don't see it as black/white, but dependant of what's the data and purpose of the comparison. As a side note, `flake8` still flags an error when using `== False`.

Comment: What purpose would justify reference identity testing rather than value comparison for logical values? I think it's pretty black-and-white (apart from the fact that there's no reason *ever* to explicitly compare logical values, hence flake8's warning).

Comment: Cool, thanks for pointing it out. To be clear, I'm not recommending anyone to use the second example in my answer here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this,

```
for i in roll_number[:]:
    if i not in sample_dict.values():
        roll_number.remove(i)
```

Output

```
print(roll_number)
# [47, 69, 76, 97]
```

- Use `not in`
- Iterating and updating the same list, it's the wrong way of doing it. so iterate through the copy `roll_number[:]`